# How to test the data displayed on the webpage is the same from the data feed(microsoft excel sheet) using selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to test a website which displays all the data from microsoft excel sheet in the table format which is known as data feed.
Can any one please help me in finding a solution to use selenium ide to test whether the data displayed on the web page is the same from the data feed using some unique column from data feed.

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this using the DataDriven plugin for Selenium IDE. (http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/datadriven)
This plugin also requires the Flow Control plugin (also called Sideflow)
and the Include plugin (there is a separate version for Selenium IDE, be careful to get the correct version).

One thing you would need to do would be to export the excel data to the xml format that the plugin requires. I used the following Excel macro to accomplish it:

```
    Sub MakeDataFile()

    Dim FileNo As Integer
    Dim CurrentLine As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim MyLoopIndex As Integer
    Dim NumRows As Integer
    Dim NumCols As Integer
    NumRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    NumCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    QT = Chr(34)
    Filename = "C:\YourFolder\YourDataFile.xml"
    FileNo = FreeFile
    Open Filename For Output As #FileNo
    ' write header to file
    Print #FileNo, "<testdata>"
    ' loop the sheet and write the data
    For MyRowIndex = 2 To NumRows
     OutputString = "<test "
     For MyColIndex = 1 To NumCols
      OutputString = OutputString & Cells(1, MyColIndex) & "=" & QT & Cells(MyRowIndex,        MyColIndex) & QT & " "
     Next MyColIndex
     OutputString = OutputString & " />"
     Print #FileNo, OutputString
    Next MyRowIndex

    ' write footer to file
    Print #FileNo, "</testdata>"
    Close #FileNo

    End Sub
```

I did not make the macro smart enough to handle the less than character, which wants to be expressed as:

```
&lt;
```

Depending on your data, there may be other special characters to handle.
The script also presumes that the spreadsheet contains field names as the first row and that the entire content of the spreadsheet is to be the intended data to capture.